# Control other app widget in andrioid

Tags: android, widget, launcher

I have launcher application and has draw over app permission. I don't need to allow widget on my launcher. How can I control other app widgets?
Eg: When I'm in Launcher and a message received in facebook messenger, The messenger head will come over my launcher. I don't need to allow widget on my launcher. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Could you try to re-formulate your question? - maybe provide a picture/code or similar to picture what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Facebook "chatheads" have nothing to do with app widgets, AFAIK. What evidence do you have that Facebook "chatheads" are tied to launchers and app widgets?

Comment: I need to disable all widgets when my app is opened. The widget will not be enabled automatically like chat heads automatically enabling while the message received.